# If $a_n$ is a decreasing series of positive numbers show that $c_n = \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n a_i}+ \sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> If $a_n$ is a decreasing series of positive numbers show that $$c_n = \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n a_i}+ \sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^n}(n \rightarrow \infty)$$
>
> a) converges
>
> b) to a value less than or equal to $2a_1$

I had no trouble showing that the max value at the limit is $2a_1$, but I'm having a little trouble proving that it converges.

Any tips?

Comment: the first $\sqrt[n]{?}$ is a decreasing sequence, the second $\sqrt[n]{?}$ is sandwitched between $a_1$ and $\sqrt[n]{n} a_1$.

Comment: Why is the first decreasing? It seems a little tricky since the next one is of $\sqrt[n+1]{...}$

Comment: $a_1,\ldots,a_n \ge a_{n+1} \implies (\prod_{k=1}^n a_k)^{1/n} \ge
 a_{n+1} \implies\\ (\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}a_k)^{1/(n+1)} = ((\prod_{k=1}^n a_k)a_k)^{1/(n+1)} \ge ((\prod_{k=1}^{n}a_k)^{1+1/n})^{1/(n+1)} = (\prod_{k=1}^n a_k)^{1/n}
$

Comment: What if $a_1=2/10 ; a_2 = 1/10 ; a_3 = 5/100$ then $a_1 \cdot a_2 = 2/100 < 5 /100$

Comment: oops, I reversed the inequality in last line. should be $
 (\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}a_k)^{1/(n+1)} = ((\prod_{k=1}^n a_k)a_k)^{1/(n+1)} \color{red}{\le} ((\prod_{k=1}^{n}a_k)^{1+1/n})^{1/(n+1)} = (\prod_{k=1}^n a_k)^{1/n}$. For your what if, $(a_1a_2)^{\color{red}{1/2}} > 5/100$

Comment: The first term converges because $\{a_k\}$ converges, so $\{\ln a_k\}$ converges  and hence the Cesaro averages  $\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln a_k$ also converge. (Take exponential to show that the first term converges).

Comment: @achillehui Thanks, my bad for missing the $1/n$ power.